# Fight simulator with random numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that simulates a fight. So far I have a list and something that picks at random one of them that I found in another post. I can't seem to make an `if` statement that prints out “Hit!” or “Dodge!” or “Critical Hit!” when it chooses the respective word because it gives a syntax error for whatever reason. Can anyone help me? What do I do so I can make the `if` statement?

```
Health = 10
dodge = 1
dmg = 1
hit = dmg + 1
crhit = hit * 2

def fight():
    while 1 == 1:
        global Health
        global dodge
        global hit
        global dmg
        chances = [hit, hit, dodge, crhit, hit]
        from random import choice
fight()
```

Comment: i don't see an `if` statement that would give you a syntax error for "whatever" reason. your code doesn't do anything, apart from looping endlessly over an `import` statement

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full `SyntaxError` you're receiving and the *actual code* you're running that produces that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not gonna give away the entire answer, since you should work at that, but doing `random.choice(testList)` returns a random element from the list, you can use these to get one from `hit`, `dodge` and `crhit`. You can just write three `if-elif` statements to check for each. Short examples (you should get your answer from here),

```
>>> varOne = 2
>>> varTwo = 3
>>> varThree = 4
>>> from random import choice
>>> testVar = choice([varOne, varTwo, varThree])
>>> if testVar == varOne:
       print 'abc'
    elif testVar == varTwo:
       print 'def'
    else:
       print 'ghi'


abc
```

Comment: I did almost exactly that, but instead of doing it when I run it it restarts.

Comment: Restarts? You mean it doesn't print out anything to the screen?

Comment: Yes. It prints out Restart to the screen.

Comment: Use a `while` loop to keep taking inputs until a break condition is reached.

Comment: Thanks! I found out why, it was because I had put 's around say varOne.

Answer (score 2):

You have only *imported* the function choice, you still have to *call* it:

```
from random import choice # This makes it so we can use the function in the script.
Health = 10
dodge = 1
dmg = 1
hit = dmg + 1
crhit = hit * 2
def fight():
    while 1:
        mychoice = choice(chances) # We call the function. It gets a random value from the list
        if mychoice == hit: # Create an if/elif for each possible outcome
            dostuff()
        elif ...
fight()
```

Then you can use an `if/elif` structure to do stuff with each option

Also, those `global` statements are not needed, as you actually aren't modifying the variables themselves (Unless you plan on doing this later).

`while 1 == 1` can simply be written as `while 1`, as that can also be considered `True`.